# Magento 2 : Reformatting Luma Product Page

Tags: magento2, product, blocks, design

So I'm attempting to make my product detail page look nicer.

[image]

As you can see it's a mess. I need to rearrange order and spacing. I've switched on template path and block hints in developer mode, but that doesn't help. I'm not worried about CSS right now, just positioning. Every tutorial I can find applies to a different Magento version where directory structure is totally different.

If anyone can point me in a direction for a good tutorial or give me some info I'd appreciate it.

This is a child theme based on Luma, Magento V 2.0.13

I'm a newb - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently i am also building my own theme but i extend from blank and its not easy for me. But I give you a bit summarized steps what I have done. Since your theme is the child theme for luma, you need to create a directory Magento_Catalog/layout, Magento_Catalog/templates,  Magento_Catalog/web (notice the capital letters) inside your theme folder.

Then, you need to copy :

- all catalog_product_"all".xml files ("all" is the wildcard) from app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/ to your newly created Magento_Catalog/layout. These are the layout xml for product details page.
- all files and folder from app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/ to your newly created Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view.

I am not sure how you wanted it to look like, but you can start from xml files first then work you way to templates phtml files

Comment: Thanks for your response Afham. But I don't have a code directory inside my app directory. My tree is app/design/frontend/Magento. This is where i get confused. Are we running the same version of Magento?

Comment: i think your version is a bit older than mine. Then your app/code/Magento directory maybe located somewhere else. Try take a look at lib or vendor folder